# Saving an entire site offline for iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, web, native, offline

I'm looking for a tool that will let me save a simple HTML site and all of its contents for offline viewing on iOS and Android.

I've tried saving files offline in Dropbox and Google Drive. Neither worked. Any other ideas?

Are there any dev tools that I can use to wrap up the site and convert it to a native app? The key is that it has to be fully accessible offline.

Comment: you don't need a tool. You only need to download the files to your android and open the main/index file on chrome. Than you have the offline site in your android.

Comment: @andre_vieira that doesnt help what so ever for other users.

Comment: @andre_vieira Thanks. I'm mainly concerned about iOS. I think most of the mobile use will be via iPad

Comment: and you can't do that in IOS? because I use something similar, and I just put the code and static content to a zip, transfer  the zip via email, or google drive to the phone, extract, and open the index. And I have the fully offline site at my phone

Comment: @andre_vieira No. iOS doesn't seem to open files that way. There are a couple 3rd party apps, but they aren't playing well with JS. I basically need something that I can use to wrap my website and distribute it as a native app for Android and iOS that will function offline.

Comment: @Ward, could you please share the link to your website?

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you convert any website into a native app?
   We can try to achieve this but it will be hard to give the same experience. There is lot of dependency on the architecture of the website and security implementations. Codium Labs have tried this http://codiumlabs.com/ios/offline-pages/
2. Is offline viewing of any website possible?
   You can somewhat achieve this by converting the web page you are viewing into a pdf and saving it for later reference. I think saving on Dropbox and Google Drive does the same.
3. Can we build websites to work offline?
   Yes. But I'm not sure whether that is what you are after here.

Comment: Thanks. This is for an interactive demo. Like a prototype. It's essentially like navigating through screenshots where each page has a bunch of hotspots that point to other pages in the site. On a desktop/laptop I can just open it in a browser on the desktop. The problem is mobile without a connection.